# Splitting a string to tokens according to shell parameter rules without eval

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a string like

```
$ str="abc 'e f g' hij"
```

and i wish to get whole `e f g` part of it. In other words, i wish to tokenize the string according to shell parameter rules.

Currently, i am doing that as

```
$ str="abc 'e f g' hij"; (eval "set -- $str"; echo $2)
```

but this is totally unsafe if a single `*` gets outside of `'`-ticks.

Any better solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set -f` to disable filename expansion altogether.

```
$ str="* 'e f g' hij"
$ ( set -f; eval "set -- $str"; echo $2 )
e f g
```

This addresses just one problem you might anticipate with `eval`, but there may be other options available with `set` you can explore.