# Bash: Tokenize string using shell rules without eval'ing it?

Tags: python, bash, eval, shlex

I'm writing a wrapper script. The original program's arguments are in a separate file, `args`. The script needs to **split contents of `args` using shell parameter rules** and then run the program. A partial solution (`set` + `eval`) was offered in [Splitting a string to tokens according to shell parameter rules without eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913678/splitting-a-string-to-tokens-according-to-shell-parameter-rules-without-eval):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
STDOUT="$1"
STDERR="$2"
( set -f ; eval "set -- $(cat args)"; exec run_in_container "$@" >"$STDOUT" 2>"$STDERR" )
```

but in my case `args` is user-generated. One can easily imagine

- `args`: `echo "Hello, 'world'! $(rm -rf /)"` (not cool, but harmless: commands are run in a e.g. docker container)
- `args`: `bash -c "$JAVA_HOME/<...> > <...> && <...>"` (harmful: `$JAVA_HOME` was intended to be **container**'s value of environment variable `JAVA_HOME`, but actually will be substituted earlier, when `eval`'ing the command in the wrapper script's subshell.)

I tried Python, and this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shlex, subprocess, sys

with open('args', 'r') as argsfile:
    args = argsfile.read()

with open(sys.argv[1], 'w') as outfile, open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as errfile:
    exit(subprocess.call(["run_in_container"] + shlex.split(args), stdout=outfile, stderr=errfile))
```

**Is there a way to do `shlex` in bash**: tokenize the string using shell parameter rules, but don't substitute any variables' values, don't execute `$(...)` etc.?

Comment: I doubt it's (easily and safely) possible, and I'd even say it's a bad idea to go along that path.

Comment: A bad idea to use bash when there is a perfectly acceptable Python script that does the deed? Perhaps it is, but I'm just curious if it is possible in bash

Comment: if the user determines the args anyway whats to stop them just passing in `rm -rf /` ?

Comment: Nothing. The command will be run in an isolated environment, e.g. docker container, so that's not the problem. **Unexpected variable substitution** into "args" is the problem.